# Sprite buttons that expand when clicked in Cocos2D V3

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to create a button that always uses the same sprite, and which scales up a little and back down again whenever it is tapped. Here's how I create the button:

```
CCSpriteFrame *sprite = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"my-sprite.png"];

CCButton *button = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@""
                                 spriteFrame:sprite
                      highlightedSpriteFrame:sprite
                         disabledSpriteFrame:nil];

[button setTarget:self selector:@selector(onButtonPressed:)];

[self addChild:button];
```

The button shows up and properly calls the selector, but it does not expand when clicked. What do I need to change in order to fix this?

Comment: unfortunately not documented here http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCButton.html but ccbutton has a property that enables this tap/scale behavior. Look through CCButton.h should be easy to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button.zoomWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

As suggested by @LearnCocos2d, the property `BOOL zoomWhenHighlighted` could be used to get the affect that you want. You may also want to play around with the scaleTo values in implementation CCButton.m

```
if (_zoomWhenHighlighted)
            {
                [_label runAction:[CCActionScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.1 scaleX:_originalScaleX*1.2 scaleY:_originalScaleY*1.2]];
                [_background runAction:[CCActionScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.1 scaleX:_originalScaleX*1.2 scaleY:_originalScaleY*1.2]];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 images:

1. One for normal
2. Next for press (same canvas size of above but image scaled to < 100% )

Then use:

```
CCSpriteFrame *backButtonSprite = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"backButton.png"];
CCSpriteFrame *backButtonPressedSprite = [CCSpriteFrame
                                          frameWithImageNamed:@"backButtonPressed.png"];

CCButton *myButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@""
                                    priteFrame:backButtonSprite
                        highlightedSpriteFrame:backButtonPressedSprite
                           disabledSpriteFrame:nil];

[myButton setTarget:self selector:@selector(myFunction:)]; 
myButton = ccp(100,100);
[self addChild:backButton];
```

[image]

Keep Coding............... :)